# How to load functions based on the page title of an HTML page created and shown using showModalDialog()?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating a web page, whose title may change depending on which button the user clicks. When the page loads its `HTML` part, I'd like to run a function of 2 depending on the `pageTitle` passed.

I'm not sure why this is not working the way it is.

**Function to display the page**

```
function showPoPage(poPage, pageTitle) {
  const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(poPage);
  const html = template.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  html.setWidth(1400).setHeight(800)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, pageTitle);
}
```

**The script piece which doesn't seem to be running correctly**

```
...(embeded into the HTML)
<script>
const pageTitle = document.getElementByClassName('modal-dialog-title-text').innerText;
console.log('Page Title found on top: ' + pageTitle)// Nothing shows in the logs
if (pageTitle == 'Edit PO') {
  loadPODataToEdit();
} else if (pageTitle === 'Fabric-Colombia PO') {
  loadOrderPosFromSS();
  loadUnit();
}
</script>
```

**The error in the console**

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function
```

I'm not sure what the rules are for running this script containing such criteria and behavior.

Comment: Should it be `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementByClassName`? Typographical error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your showing script, it seems that you are using HTML template. I thought that this might be able to be used for achieving your goal. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function showPoPage(poPage, pageTitle) {
  const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(poPage);
  template.title = pageTitle; // <--- Added
  const html = template.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  html.setWidth(1400).setHeight(800)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, pageTitle);
}
```

#### HTML side:

```html
...(embeded into the HTML)
<script>
const pageTitle = "<?!= title ?>"; // <--- Modified
console.log('Page Title found on top: ' + pageTitle)// Nothing shows in the logs
if (pageTitle == 'Edit PO') {
  loadPODataToEdit();
} else if (pageTitle === 'Fabric-Colombia PO') {
  loadOrderPosFromSS();
  loadUnit();
}
</script>
```

- By this modification, you can run the functions by the value of `pageTitle`.

Comment: I had to go back and have a look at ```scriptlets``` so I could make it work. Thank you!

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.